# Why I'm getting this error "AttributeError: 'linkList' object has no attribute 'data'" Merge Sorted link list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

Why I am getting this error? I have written all corrected but still not resolved.

Reversing the link list with optimal solution. Python programming

File "d:\DSA_Parctice\3_MonthsDSA\LinkList\ReverseLinkList.py", line 74, in
mergeTwoSortedLinkListOptimize
if list2.data <= list1.data:
AttributeError: 'linkList' object has no attribute 'data'

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class linkList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Head=None
    
    def insertAtBeg(self,data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        if self.Head == None:
            self.Head = newNode
            return
        temp=self.Head
        self.Head=newNode
        self.Head.next=temp


    def reverseLinkList(self):
        preNode=None
        currHead=self.Head
        nextNode=self.Head
        while currHead!=None:
            nextNode=currHead.next
            currHead.next=preNode
            preNode=currHead
            currHead=nextNode
        self.Head=preNode 

    def printLinkList(self):
        if self.Head==None:
            print("Link List is Empty")
        else:
            temp=self.Head
            while temp!=None:
                print(temp.data, end=" ")
                temp=temp.next

    def mergeTwoSortedLinkListOptimize(list1,list2):
        mergeList=Node(0)
        mergeList.next = list1
        while True:

            if list1 is None:
                list1 = list2
                break
                
            if list2 is None:
                break
            
            if list2.data <= list1.data:
                temp = list1
                list1= list2
                list2 = list2.next
                list1.next= temp
            
            else: list1=  list1.next
        return mergeList.next

llist1=linkList()
llist1.insertAtBeg(3)
llist1.insertAtBeg(5)
llist1.insertAtBeg(6)
llist1.insertAtBeg(8)
llist1.insertAtBeg(9)
llist1.insertAtBeg(10)

llist2 = linkList()
llist2.insertAtBeg(1)
llist2.insertAtBeg(6)
llist2.insertAtBeg(7)
llist2.insertAtBeg(15)
llist1.reverseLinkList()
llist2.reverseLinkList()
llist1.printLinkList()
print()
llist2.printLinkList()

llist1=llist1.mergeTwoSortedLinkListOptimize(llist2)
llist1.printLinkList()

#  I tried also like this "if temp1[0].data <= temp2[0].data:" but not resolved
      
# Why I am getting this error i have written all corrected but still not resolved.

File "d:DSA\LinkList\ReverseLinkList.py", line 74, in mergeTwoSortedLinkListOptimize
    if list2.data <= list1.data:
AttributeError: 'linkList' object has no attribute 'data'

Please help me I am trying from two days
```

Comment: I have tried with self also but getting same error like that                                                    
    def mergeTwoSortedLinkListOptimize(self,list1,list2):
        self.mergeList=Node(0)
        self.mergeList.next = list1                                                                                                                                                          ll3 = linkList()
ll3=ll3.mergeTwoSortedLinkListOptimize(llist1,llist2)
llist1.printLinkList()

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this wrong.

1. `mergeList=Node(0)` this doesn't make sense. This should be an instance of `linkList` and not a standalone `Node`.
2. `list1.data` does not exist because it's a `linkList` object. See the definition of your `linkList` class. It has no member other than `self.Head`.
3. Your merging strategy is wrong.
4. `mergeTwoSortedLinkListOptimize` should be a separate utility function and should not be a member of `linkList` class because its job is to combine two `linkList` objects. So, it does not make sense to make it a member of the `linkList` class.

The fixed code is given below.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class linkList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Head = None

    def insertAtBeg(self, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        if self.Head == None:
            self.Head = newNode
            return
        temp = self.Head
        self.Head = newNode
        self.Head.next = temp

    def reverseLinkList(self):
        preNode = None
        currHead = self.Head
        nextNode = self.Head
        while currHead != None:
            nextNode = currHead.next
            currHead.next = preNode
            preNode = currHead
            currHead = nextNode
        self.Head = preNode

    def printLinkList(self):
        if self.Head == None:
            print("Link List is Empty")
        else:
            temp = self.Head
            while temp != None:
                print(temp.data, end=" ")
                temp = temp.next


def mergeTwoSortedLinkListOptimize(list1: linkList, list2: linkList):
    # result linked list
    mergeList = linkList()

    # if either linked list is None, nothing to do other than returning the
    # other list
    if list1 is None:
        mergeList = list2

    if list2 is None:
        mergeList = list1

    # if neither is None, we can perform some comparisons
    if list1 is not None and list2 is not None:
        list1_current_loc = list1.Head
        list2_current_loc = list2.Head

        while True:
            # if at the last node (node.next is None), break
            if list1_current_loc is None or list2_current_loc is None:
                break

            # compare and put the data in the result linked list
            if list1_current_loc.data <= list2_current_loc.data:
                mergeList.insertAtBeg(list1_current_loc.data)
                list1_current_loc = list1_current_loc.next
            else:
                mergeList.insertAtBeg(list2_current_loc.data)
                list2_current_loc = list2_current_loc.next

    # copy over any remaining items
    while list1_current_loc is not None:
        mergeList.insertAtBeg(list1_current_loc.data)
        list1_current_loc = list1_current_loc.next

    while list2_current_loc is not None:
        mergeList.insertAtBeg(list2_current_loc.data)
        list2_current_loc = list2_current_loc.next

    return mergeList


llist1 = linkList()
llist1.insertAtBeg(3)
llist1.insertAtBeg(5)
llist1.insertAtBeg(6)
llist1.insertAtBeg(8)
llist1.insertAtBeg(9)
llist1.insertAtBeg(10)

llist2 = linkList()
llist2.insertAtBeg(1)
llist2.insertAtBeg(6)
llist2.insertAtBeg(7)
llist2.insertAtBeg(15)
llist1.reverseLinkList()
llist2.reverseLinkList()
llist1.printLinkList()
print()
llist2.printLinkList()
print()
llist1 = mergeTwoSortedLinkListOptimize(llist1, llist2)
llist1.printLinkList()
```

Comment: Hi, your code is looking nice and it's working, but I didn't understand why you use here list1.Head. Can you explain a little about that?

Comment: list1 is a `linkList` object. In linked lists, you always start from the `head` or `root` of the linked list in order to traverse it. In your `linkList` class, you assign `self.Head = None` in the constructor, and the class has no other attributes. Hence, when I want to traverse the list, I start at the `Head` of the list.